# How to backup wlan configuration?

Tags: configuration, wifi, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 and I'd like to copy all files containing the configuration to access all wireless network which I usually use.

At home or at office it connects automatic.

I know that I can edit the connection using the icon but I believe that there is a file containing the login and passwords and all the protocols, anyway, all the set up to the wireless connections.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If LXDE uses the same NetworkManager Applet(nm-applet) that gnome uses, just make a backup of the following directory and file inside your HOME:

```
~/.gconf/system/networking/
~/.gnome2/keyrings
```

Then, you should find information about your wireless connections inside these files.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the folder `~/.gconf/system`. Inside the second one I have two non text files: `login.keyring` and `login.keystore`. I didn't find any text file with name of connections, etc...

Comment: For others who may not think they have either of these directories, make sure you're using the `-a` switch with `ls`. (Or in your GUI-based file browser, have 'show hidden files' or 'show dot files' enabled.)